# Union of three axes is not isomorphic to 3 lines in a plane.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subset \mathbb{A}_k^3:xy=xz=yz=0$ and $Y\subset \mathbb{A}_k^3:z=xy(x+y)=0$. My definition is that two algebraic sets are isomorphic if there exists mutually inverse polynomial maps between them. Are they isomorphic? My attempts to find polynomial maps was failed. And I saw in [a book](http://books.google.co.kr/books?id=_XxZdhbtf1sC&pg=PA177&lpg=PA177&dq=union%20of%20three%20coordinate%20axes%20isomorphic&source=bl&ots=3m5pPlxMoz&sig=tr3yUWJDGvrM4o1auJ9MNsaqbQM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=76jBUKneHcyViAemkICwBw&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=union%20of%20three%20coordinate%20axes%20isomorphic&f=false), they are not isomorphic because $X$ has dimension 3 tangent space, $Y$ has dimension 2 tangent space.

But if they are isomorphic, the dimension of tangent space must be preserved? And the singular the origin should go to the origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are completely right. If they were isomorphic, tangent spaces should be preserved. So since the tangent spaces have different dimension, they're not isomorphic.